# c++ - too many characters in character constant

Tags: c++

I have the following legacy code:

```
unsigned int code = 'abcd';
```

I need to add one character to the above code:

```
unsigned int code = 'abcd2';
```

but then I get the following error: too many characters in character constant. Why using `unsigned long int` type doesn't resolve that issue ? Is it possible to fix it or I should modify the code and use a char array ?

Comment: I know but that's a legacy code which compiles.

Comment: @kiranBiradar in C multi-character literals are legal. Their value is implementation defined. Not sure about C++

Comment: you need to explain what that line is supposed to do, because it isnt obvious. Why `unsigned int` ? Why `'abcd'` not `"abcd"` ? I guess the latter is the actual problem, but to fix your code also the first needs to be clarified

Comment: You mention C++ but added C and C++. Which language do you use?

Comment: If you need to extend that sequence, I would assume you know, what value should be assigned. Why not provide a proper hex or decimal integer literal instead of that non-portable beast? Also: What value do you expect to get when you add another character?

Comment: The project contains C and C++ code, but is compiled as C++.

Comment: "Why using unsigned long int type doesn't resolve that issue ?" It sounds like int and long are both 32-bit on your system, so try uint64_t. Or stick with codes that are four characters or less.

Comment: @Gerhardh Could you please describe in more details when the above code is not portable ? I guess that an author has created that code to get a simple string literal to int conversion...

Comment: You might start with printing the result of that assignment. What is the value of that literal? The C standard defines that the value of this is implementation defined. Any compiler vendor can do what they want. E.g. they could just use first char and drop the rest. Or only the last char. Or the could tread as 4 bytes. Whatever they like. How could this possible be portable? If a string was meant, what is the value? Should it be handled as a hex digit? A set of 4 8bit values? Try to get rid of that thing. Fast! ;)

Comment: IMO if you need recommendation of best solution you should provide more context how `code` is used (kind of logic it participates).

Comment: C11: 6.4.4; 10 ... The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or ..., is implementation-defined

Comment: When a file is compiled as C++, it contains C++ code. Some of it may be C-like C++ code, but it is nonetheless C++. Do not tag questions about it with the C tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why using unsigned long int type doesn't resolve that issue ?

Because the type of the variable has no effect on the type of the literal. The type of multi-char literal is `int`. There are no `unsigned long` multi-char literals.

Also, on some systems `unsigned long` has exactly as many bytes as `int` has.

> Is it possible to fix it

There is no way to fit more characters in multi-char literal.

> or I should modify the code and use a char array ?

If you need more characters, then yes.